# Define measure through a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let us define a measure as follows:

$\nu (B) := \pi^{-d/2} \int_B \exp (-\vert x\vert ^2)\mathrm{d}m^d(x)$
where $m^d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Is there a obvious interpretation of this measure?

Comment: This is [Gaussian measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_measure) with mean zero and variance $1/2$.  What do you want to know about it?

Comment: For the moment that is all I wanted to know, Thanks a lot! Is there also a name for the following measure defined and the sphere $\mathbb{S}^d$: $\nu (A) := \int_A f d \sigma$ where $f$ is an arbitrary fixed continuous function and $\sigma$ is the surface measure?

Comment: Please ask that as a new question.  Asking new questions in comments is bad practice; people can't find them easily.

Comment: ok, done, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

This is [Gaussian measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_measure) with mean zero and variance $1/2$.

Comment: thanks! I am asking why this measure is inner regular. Do you have a formal proof for that (since we know it is a radon measure)?